# PHP mysql Sort JSON data by keys

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, sql-order-by

I want to sort the json data but the sorting shows it wrong.
what is the reason of this ?
below is the name of my database table I have given **pages** column name **page_content** and json data below. Where am I making a mistake? I'm new here. Please be happy if you act accordingly.

**Database data page_content**

```
{
    "kind":"video",
    "etag":"edtags",
    "id":"id",
    "statistics":{
        "viewCount":"1434348",
    }
}
{
    "kind":"video",
    "etag":"edtags",
    "id":"id",
    "statistics":{
        "viewCount":"16058462",
    }
}
{
    "kind":"video",
    "etag":"edtags",
    "id":"id",
    "statistics":{
        "viewCount":"2176846",
    }
}
{
    "kind":"video",
    "etag":"edtags",
    "id":"id",
    "statistics":{
        "viewCount":"8088410",
    }
}
{
    "kind":"video",
    "etag":"edtags",
    "id":"id",
    "statistics":{
        "viewCount":"9885758",
    }
}
{
    "kind":"video",
    "etag":"edtags",
    "id":"id",
    "statistics":{
        "viewCount":"26795682",
    }
}
{
    "kind":"video",
    "etag":"edtags",
    "id":"id",
    "statistics":{
        "viewCount":"323810",
    }
}
{
    "kind":"video",
    "etag":"edtags",
    "id":"id",
    "statistics":{
        "viewCount":"529588",
    }
}
{
    "kind":"video",
    "etag":"edtags",
    "id":"id",
    "statistics":{
        "viewCount":"6416534",
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM pages order by JSON_EXTRACT(page_content,"$.statistics.viewCount") ASC');
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row ) {

    foreach ($row as $value) {

        $json = json_decode($value['page_content'], true);
        $videoView = $json['statistics']['viewCount'];

        echo $videoView;

    }
}
```

**print_r**

```
9885758
8088410
6416534
529588
323810
26795682
2176846
16058462
1434348
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unquote the json value, and cast it to a number so you can use it for proper ordering. You can do both at once as follows:

```
order by page_content ->> '$.statistics.viewCount' + 0
```

If your version of MySQL does not support operator `->>`, then:

```
order by json_extract(page_content, '$.statistics.viewCount')) + 0
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b98d25d66e83aeb4b386c4c411d9313)** - both queries yield:

```
| page_content                                                                             |
| :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| {"id": "id", "etag": "edtags", "kind": "video", "statistics": {"viewCount": "323810"}}   |
| {"id": "id", "etag": "edtags", "kind": "video", "statistics": {"viewCount": "529588"}}   |
| {"id": "id", "etag": "edtags", "kind": "video", "statistics": {"viewCount": "1434348"}}  |
| {"id": "id", "etag": "edtags", "kind": "video", "statistics": {"viewCount": "2176846"}}  |
| {"id": "id", "etag": "edtags", "kind": "video", "statistics": {"viewCount": "6416534"}}  |
| {"id": "id", "etag": "edtags", "kind": "video", "statistics": {"viewCount": "8088410"}}  |
| {"id": "id", "etag": "edtags", "kind": "video", "statistics": {"viewCount": "9885758"}}  |
| {"id": "id", "etag": "edtags", "kind": "video", "statistics": {"viewCount": "16058462"}} |
| {"id": "id", "etag": "edtags", "kind": "video", "statistics": {"viewCount": "26795682"}} |
```

Comment: error
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>> '$.statistics.viewCount' + 0 ASC' at line 1 in \vlog.php:2 Stack trace: #0 \vlog.php(2): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM p...') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\sonsurum\app\controller\vlog.php(3): require('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\sonsurum\index.php(34):

Comment: @KaanDemir: it looks like your MySQL version does not support operator `->>`. See my updated answer.

Comment: If there is a word instead of a number, will it continue at the time?

Comment: @KaanDemir: if `viewCount` is not a number (and does not start with a number), it will be converted to `0`, and ordered accordingly.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93f677e4b04dc6201af0582f05dde5e1

can you look here again **title**

Comment: @KaanDemir: if you want to order by a string rather than a number, then remove `+ 0` at the end of the query...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218395/discussion-between-kaan-demir-and-gmb).

Comment: when i shoot the series makes it different in my php: S wonder why